# i want to create a dataset excel using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, dataset

I'm working on a Python Tkinter application where I want to allow users to create a dataset by specifying the number of rows and columns. I want to achieve this by opening a new window that prompts the user to input the number of rows and columns. After this input, I'd like to dynamically generate a table in the same window where users can enter data for each cell.
Here's a simplified version of my code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, simpledialog

class DatasetCreator:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.create_button_frame()

    def create_button_frame(self):
        button_frame = ttk.Frame(self.master, padding=(10, 10, 10, 10))
        button_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.create_button(button_frame, "Create Dataset", self.create_dataset_window)

    def create_button(self, frame, text, command):
        button = tk.Button(frame, text=text, command=command)
        button.pack()

    def create_dataset_window(self):
        config_window = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        config_window.title("Dataset Configuration")

        # Ask the user for the number of rows and columns
        num_rows = simpledialog.askinteger("Dataset Configuration", "Enter the number of rows:")
        num_columns = simpledialog.askinteger("Dataset Configuration", "Enter the number of columns:")

        # TODO: Generate a table/grid for data entry
```

In the create_dataset_window function, I'm currently using simpledialog.askinteger to get the number of rows and columns, but I'm unsure how to proceed with dynamically generating a table for data entry.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or examples on how to create a dynamic table/grid in Tkinter for data entry based on the user-defined number of rows and columns.

Comment: You could use a nested for loop with the provided row and col counts to create entries and pack them with `.grid()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a nested list with all the needed entries via list comprehension. Then display the entries with a nested for loop by iteration over the rows and cols of your matrix using the `grid` manager:

```py
# list comprehension to create entry matrix
entry_matrix = [[tk.Entry(config_window) for cell in range(num_columns)] for row in range(num_rows)]

# nested for loop to pack entries
for r, row in enumerate(entry_matrix, 1):
    tk.Label(config_window, text=r).grid(row=r, column=0)
    for c, cell in enumerate(row, 1):
        # first iteration crate labels
        if r == 1:
            tk.Label(config_window, text=alphabet[c-1]).grid(row=0, column=c)
        cell.grid(row=r, column=c)
```

To use the values entered in your table you can use the same logic to implement some `IntVar` or `StringVar` matrix and assigning the respective variable to the `textvariable` attribute of the entries:

```py
# list comprehension to create variable matrix
variable_matrix = [[tk.StringVar(config_window, value='') for col in range(num_columns)]
                   for row in range(num_rows)]
# list comprehension to create entry matrix with assigned StringVars
entry_matrix = [[tk.Entry(config_window, textvariable=variable_matrix[row][col]) for col in range(num_columns)]
                for row in range(num_rows)]
# nested for loop to pack entries
for r, row in enumerate(entry_matrix, 1):
    tk.Label(config_window, text=r).grid(row=r, column=0)
    for c, cell in enumerate(row, 1):
        # first iteration crate labels
        if r == 1:
            tk.Label(config_window, text=alphabet[c-1]).grid(row=0, column=c)
        cell.grid(row=r, column=c)
# print data on button press
tk.Button(config_window, text='print Data', command=lambda: self.print_data(variable_matrix)
          ).grid(row=num_rows + 1, column=0, columnspan=2)
```

The `print_data` function could look something like this:

```py
@staticmethod
def print_data(matrix):
    # get values from entry variables
    data = [[cell.get() for cell in row] for row in matrix]
    # print to console
    print(*data, sep='\n')
```

From there on you should be able to implement your own usecase on your own.